# Unable to delete an item from a listview

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso

I have select the item, and dragged to left. but i am unable to click on delete image.

```
onView(withId(R.id.storewalk_list)) .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, swipeLeft()));
```

[image]

[image]

in this images, to the right side after every product there is GAP, which has similar properties

I have tried with following code:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.delete_button), isDisplayed())).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0,click()));
```

It is giving me an error :

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: com.cit:id/delete_button and has parent matching: (with id: com.cit:id/swipeActions and has parent matching: with id: com.cit:id/swipe_layout) and is clickable)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

can someone please let me know, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Presumably each item in that list has an element with ID `R.id.delete_button`. See https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists

Comment: this is more on recyclerview, which does not work. i think it will work with childview. can you help with this... also i do not want to match text

Comment: The page I linked to covers the `RecyclerView` case as well.

Comment: onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.delete_button))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,
                        click()));  ...getting the same error

Comment: Got the Solution :- https://mobikul.com/recycler-view-multiple-match-problem-in-espresso/

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by creating custom class..

https://mobikul.com/recycler-view-multiple-match-problem-in-espresso/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `ViewAction` that takes in the matcher of the selected position:

```
public static ViewAction actionOnView(Matcher<View> matcher, ViewAction action) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(withParent(isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class)), isDisplayed());;
        }

        @Override public String getDescription() {
            return String.format("performing ViewAction: %s on item matching %s", action.getDescription(), matcher);
        }

        @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            List<View> matches = new ArrayList<>();
            for (View item : TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view)) {
                if (matcher.matches(item)) {
                    matches.add(item);
                }
            }
            switch (matches.size()) {
                default: throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Ambiguous views found %s", matcher));
                case 0: throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No view found %s", matcher));
                case 1: action.perform(uiController, matches.get(0));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Assume the delete button is already visible, then you can do:

```
onView(withId(R.id.storewalk_list)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, actionOnView(withId(R.id.delete_button), click())))
```